# How to convert MySQL data to accentuation in Portuguese

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cakephp, character-encoding

I'm trying to migrate a site to WordPress. The site is in Portuguese. The original site database contains Portuguese words. I can view the word 'Alérgicos'  as 'AlÃ©rgicos' in the database via phpMyAdmin. But in site the same word is viewed as 'Alérgicos'.

Using WordPress functions I'm importing this data to the database of new site. Now in wp_terms table the word entering is exactly ' AlÃ©rgicos'. And in browser it is appearing as same 'AlÃ©rgicos'. So how can I change the display to 'Alérgicos' or how can I convert 'AlÃ©rgicos' to 'Alérgicos' during new db insert?

Comment: what are `charset` and `collate` in old and new databases?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan old database - utf8 and utf8_general_ci . For the new Db it was utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci. I tried to change it. But it didn't worked

Comment: @sree you can't just change it after it's already imported. You need it to be correct before you bring over the data.

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored